# Kubernetes dashboard exec issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

seeing an odd behaviour with kubernetes-dashboard where the exec option is not taking me into a shell. Instead it shows me a snippet of the dashboard UI in it? Has anyone noticed this? I cannot see any errors in the logs for the same.

I am using the following dashboard yaml:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

Comment: looks like the issue is only happening in the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with the library `hterm` and Firefox that has been fixed in version 2 of the Dashboard (as it now uses `xterm`).

You can read more in the [github issue 3541](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/3541).

If you are stick to a Dashboard with the problem, you can work around it using another browser like Chrome.